# Replacing Django Template Variable with variable created via Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, django

I am very new to Django and Javascript (< 3 weeks!) and have a question that might be stupid so any help would be greatly appreciated.

In my current code, I have a table rendered in HTML with the following code:

```
<table border="1" class="dataframe">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>{{ results.0.columns.1 }}</th>
          <th>{{ results.0.columns.1 }} </th>
          <th>{{ results.0.columns.2 }} </th>
          <th>{{ results.0.columns.6 }} </th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
      {% for row in results.0.values %}
        <tr>
          <td> {{row.0}} </td>
          <td> {{row.1}} </td>
          <td><img src="{{row.2}}" alt="img" height="150"></td>
          <td> {{row.6}} </td>
        </tr>
      {% endfor %}
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

As you can see there are numerous areas where I am referencing a django template variable with the format of `{{someDjangoVariable}}`.

However, I'd like to replace these variables with variables that are created in Javascript. I am using Javascript to take some user input which ultimately changes the view of the table.

My Javascript is set up as following:

```
<script> 
     function myFunction() {
        var index = someNumber
        var string = `results.${index}.columns.0`;

     document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = string;
  }
</script>
```

The `string` variable created in Javascript results in something that completely mimicks the Django template variable. For example, `string = results.0.columns.1`.

However, I'm unsure as to how to pass this string variable into the HTML itself. The ideal from of the html would be something like this:

```
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>{{ string1 }}</th>
          <th>{{ string2 }} </th>
          <th>{{ string3 }} </th>
          <th>{{ string4 }} </th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
      {% for row in string5 %}
        <tr>
          <td> {{row.0}} </td>
          <td> {{row.1}} </td>
          <td> {{row.2}} </td>
          <td> {{row.6}} </td>
        </tr>
      {% endfor %}
      </tbody>
    </table>

Any guidance on how I can do this?
```

Comment: document.getElementByTagName('th').innerHTML = string;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you are in the browser running javascript there is no longer any concept of django templates. You are then dealing with pure html/javascript.

The three most common approaches in this situation are:

1. Deliver your html and javascript as a functioning component completely separate from your templates. Only use yourtemplates to build the initial page. Unfortunately, in most circumstances this will result in duplication of functionality.
2. Bundle the data as json with the wepage you serve then render it client-side with a javascript template language.
3. Use the same template system on both client and server. You can use any of the numerous template systems that exist (react/angular/etc) and run a node.js server to render it server-side. This can be a deep and complicated rabbit hole. Your google keywords to start would be "django javascript server side rendering"

Answer (score 1):

First, there are no stupid questions, just questions about something we don't know, so it is ok to ask.

Said that,

Django "build" the HTML of your page in the server-side, at that point, your js is not even dreaming with being executed. Javascript executes when the content (generated earlier by Django) is downloaded to your browser and is your browser the one that executes it.

As you can see you can't use js variables when generating the HTML with the Django template system. Those variables do not exist at the moment your HTML is being generated.

Since you're very new to Django as you said before, I'll give you a suggestion and is up to you to read a little about it.

### Posible approaches

1. - You can implement a view in Django, that renders some HTML using variables you pass to the view from js. And the use js to include the returned HTML in your page (DOM).
2. - You are populating a table, there are a lot of js plugins out there for rendering tables, some of then allows you to specify the data source. Use one of then an provide the data calling a with a Django view that returns the data (recommended for this: [JsonResposnse](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/request-response/#jsonresponse-objects).)
3. - Do not use the Django template system for rendering that part of your application, use just HTML + js, and use js then to call a view from Django in order to get some data.